# How can i create a google maps marker that i customize at runtime android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, marker

How can i achieve a marker like the one in the picture below,that i can customize for every item at runtime,based on the item's attributes,in this example,price.

[image]

I have some knowledge about markers and customization,so im not a complete newbie,for example i was able to achieve this:

But in this case nothing is dynamic,the marker is the same for every item so it's not like what i want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the utility library? It supports an IconGenerator class which you can use to display text on a marker. This seems to accomplish your use case.

See: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils